# Optimizing a Mysql select Query with file names and Date comparison

Tags: mysql

i need help optimizing a Mysql query:

i have two tables:

```
jos_mp3_file(id,path,version_timestamp)

jos_mp3_licenses(id,s3_url,cdate)
```

there are about 20,000 records in each.

the records in **"jos_mp3_file.path**" column, might have a folder in front of the file, like this: **'folder/file1.mp3'**.

what i need to do is find all the records where: 
1. **'jos_mp3_file.path'** has the same file name as **'jos_mp3_licenses.mp3_url'** (somehow cut through the folder part)
2. **'jos_mp3_file.version_timestamp'** is bigger than **jos_mp3_licenses.cdate** (both are *datetime* data type)

so far i have this query, but for some reason it takes a long time to run (5-10 minutes)

```
SELECT jos_mp3_licenses.s3_url, jos_mp3_licenses.cdate,  jos_mp3_file.path,jos_mp3_file.version_timestamp
FROM jos_mp3_file, jos_mp3_licenses 
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX( jos_mp3_file.path , '/', -1 ) = jos_mp3_licenses.mp3_url
AND unix_timestamp(jos_mp3_file.version_timestamp) > unix_timestamp(jos_mp3_licenses.cdate)
```

Thanks !

Comment: If you may fiddle with the table structure, add a field to jos_mp3_file which contains the file name only, add an index on this field, add an index for jos_mp3_licenses.mp3_url, tweak your query so that it uses the file name only and not the path, and the query will run 100 times faster.

Comment: is there any indexes before on these two tables, if any, so please show them or i wil provide you the indexes for your tables which definitely optimize your query execution time

Answer (score 1):

Your query is taking a long time to run probably because it is doing a nested-loop join.  That is, it is comparing every record in one table to every record in the other.  With 20k rows, this is 400 million operations.

Normally, when tables are joined, you want to do an equality operation on one or more of the fields.  Although your field has an equality, I speculate that the `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` function is being ignored for the purposes of optimization.

The best suggestion is to extract the name that you want into new column in the table.  This will allow the query to optimize.  You might then get better performance by adding an index on that column.

I would also suggest adding the unix_timestamp of the two datetime values as separate columns as well.  If you then build indexes on the two tables with the filename and the unix time stamp of the appropriate date, you should have a highly optimized query.